# Python WhiteNoise not gzip compressing in Flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, gzip

I used `WhiteNoise` in my `Flask/Python3` application with `gunicorn` being the web server as follows:

```python
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.wsgi_app = WhiteNoise(app.wsgi_app, root='static/')
app.wsgi_app.add_files(app.static_folder)
```

I even tried to create `static_folder` in `Flask object` and adding it later on to additional `WhiteNoise` files but that did not work either. It compiles fine, but when I do:

```bash
curl -i -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://my-homepage/static/css/my.css
```

I receive the following response:

```json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.8.1
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 09:53:38 GMT
Content-Length: 50162
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 May 2018 09:51:21 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Expires: Wed, 23 May 2018 21:53:38 GMT
Etag: "1527069081.0-50162-130551313"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

You can see the `Content-Encoding: gzip` not being present. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the **solution**, after a few tries. It seems that the `WhiteNoise` documentation is a little bit outdated and doesn't mention everything.

I changed the line from:

```
app.wsgi_app = WhiteNoise(app.wsgi_app, root='static/')
```

to:

```
app.wsgi_app = WhiteNoise(app.wsgi_app, root=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'), prefix='static/')
```

First of all, the `prefix`parameter is required (not mentioned in the documentation) and furthermore the `Flask` app did not know how to handle the `'static/'` path therefore an absolute path has to be provided.

Comment: So it comes down to path is incorrect, and you still need to compress it using whitenoise.compress?

Comment: Not only the path is incorrect, the `prefix` parameter is also necessary, but that's not documented in the `WhiteNoise` documentation. Also useful maybe, the `stable` WhiteNoise documentation is even more outdated, you have to use the `WhiteNoise latest` documentation: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/flask.html . Still, it does not mention the `prefix` requirement. And no, `whitenoise.compress` is not needed. I tried with and without present `.gz` files and seems `whitenoise`generates it on its own. At least that's what happened for my app on Heroku.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for partaking in trying to solve this topic.

Comment: Ran into same problem. For me combination of `prefix` and `whitenoise.compress` worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [command line utility](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/base.html#compression-support) comes with WhiteNoise to do the compression yourself.

Quote

> WhiteNoise comes with a command line utility which will generate
>   compressed versions of your files for you.

```
$ python -m whitenoise.compress --help
usage: compress.py [-h] [-q] [--no-gzip] [--no-brotli]
                   root [extensions [extensions ...]]

Search for all files inside <root> *not* matching <extensions> and produce
compressed versions with '.gz' and '.br' suffixes (as long as this results in
a smaller file)

positional arguments:
  root         Path root from which to search for files
  extensions   File extensions to exclude from compression (default: jpg,
               jpeg, png, gif, webp, zip, gz, tgz, bz2, tbz, swf, flv, woff,
               woff2)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -q, --quiet  Don't produce log output
  --no-gzip    Don't produce gzip '.gz' files
  --no-brotli  Don't produce brotli '.br' files
```

> You can either run this
>   during development and commit your compressed files to your
>   repository, or you can run this as part of your build and deploy
>   processes.

Comment: thanks that pointed me already in the right direction. I assumed `gzip` files are created from `whitenoise`. However, even after having `.gz` files in my root path I receive the same `curl` response.

Comment: I'm not sure. Do the original uncompressed files exist in the folder? Maybe try remove them.

Comment: I already tried that. Removing the original uncompressed files gives me a `404` error when trying to curl one of those `css`. Using `curl` for a `css.gz` gives me a `200` response but still the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is missing. Furthermore, I saw that the `WhiteNoise` docs don't say anything about generating the `gzip` files manually for `Flask` apps, only for `WSGI` apps.